# Combining hour and minute field into one in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I hope someone can help me with this. I have created a form using PowerApps which requires users to enter a time in the format of hours and minutes as separate fields.

I now need to create a list in SharePoint to hold the data, however, I'm not sure how to combine the hour field and minute field into one field so that a time can be kept correctly. I have been looking online and tried a few things, but SharePoint simply says "something went wrong".

Alternatively, if PowerApps has a time picker that would work too.

I probably have gone about this the wrong way. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no time picker in powerapps unfortunately. To select the current time, you can use this function: `Text( Now() ; DateTimeFormat.LongTime24 )`. This returns the current time, "09:45:10" for this moment.
Lets say you have two text inputs. One for hours (hours_input) and one for minutes (minutes_input). To merge both together you can do the following:
`hours_input & ":" & minutes_input`
**OR**
`Concatenate(hours_input.Text; ":"; minutes_input.Text)`
Best Regards